# .NET Core 6.0 Session Storage With HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a list of type UserRoleViewModel and according to the information I received from the session, I want this list to be filled. But I couldn't find how to use it in filling the list and getting data.

My method is as follows:

```
public List<UserRoleViewModel> CurrentUserAssignedRoles
{
     get
     {
         List<UserRoleViewModel> userViewModelList = new();

         if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get("CurrentUserAssignedRoles") != null)
         {
             // What I want to do here is filling the list information I got from Session into the my userViewModelList.
            // But I got an error like: Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to System.Collection.GenericList.
             list = (List<UserRoleViewModel>)httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get("CurrentUserAssignedRoles");
         }

         return list;
     }
     set
     {
            // I want to set the value information here too.
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Set("CurrentUserAssignedRoles") = value;

     }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Session` for this: user role/security information is stored in the Authentication Ticket structure that ASP.NET Core manages for you.

Comment: For scale, session only stores byte arrays so multiple web servers can share state. You can write an extension method to store UTF8 json for complex data types. However, user roles would normally be stored as claims in a cookie.

Comment: Hi @Shadouspan, what the result of your `CurrentUserAssignedRoles` session, could you pls share the value to us?